# Table 'nthb911db1.all_sequences' doesn't exist Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate mapping fille

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.nt.entity.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
        <!-- Singular ID filled config -->
        <id name="eid" column="EID" type="int">
            <generator class="sequence">
                  <param name="sequence_name">emp_seq</param>
            </generator></id>
        <property name="ename" type="string">
            <column name="ename" length="20"/>
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" length="30"/>
        </property>
        <property name="salary"  type="int">
            <column name="salary" length="10"/>
        </property>
    </class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Configuration file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- connection properties -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql:///NTHB911DB1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!-- hibernate properties -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <!-- mapping file -->
    <mapping resource="com/nt/entity/Employee.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

Error::

```
   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to build DatabaseInformation
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:140)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:96)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at com.nt.test.SaveObjectTest.main(SaveObjectTest.java:29)
  Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'nthb911db1.all_sequences' doesn't exist
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2812)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2761)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1612)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:42)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:132)
... 8 more
```

Kindly help me how to solve it please
I m trying to create table dynamically in sqlyog GUI 
But m getting error its unable to create

Showing error as 
Table 'nthb911db1.all_sequences' doesn't exist
I think i have some problem in generator statement in xml file 
Kindly suggest mme the way to resolve it

Comment: kindly any one help

Answer (score 1):

I think that, you need change the "dialect" to mysql dialect, and mysql not support "sequence" feature, may be need change this.

I hope you can understand my poor English. :)